# SQL Count Of Open Orders Each Day Between Two Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've tried searching but it's likely I'm using the wrong keywords as I can't find an answer.

I'm trying to find the number of orders that are open between two dates and by employee. I have one table that shows a list of employees, another that shows a list of orders that contains an open and close date and also a dates table if that helps.

The employee and order tables joined will return something like:

```
employee    order ref   opened          closed
a           123         01/01/2012      04/01/2012
b           124         02/01/2012      03/01/2012
a           125         02/01/2012      03/01/2012
```

And I need to transform this data into:

```
Date            employee    Count
01/01/2012      a           1
02/01/2012      a           2
02/01/2012      b           1
03/01/2012      a           2
03/01/2012      b           1
04/01/2012      a           1
```

I'm pulling the data from SQL server.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Nick

Comment: Do you need it to show zero if ther are no rows at all?

Answer (score 3):

Join `Dates` to the result of the join between `Employees` and `Orders`, then group by dates and employees to obtain the counts, something like this:

```
SELECT
  d.Date,
  o.Employee,
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM Employees e
  INNER JOIN Orders o ON e.ID = o.Employee
  INNER JOIN Dates d ON d.Date BETWEEN o.Opened AND o.Closed
GROUP BY
  d.Date,
  o.Employee
```

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way to do this counts the number of cumulative opens and the number of cumulative closes over time.

```
with cumopens as
    (select employee, opened as thedate,
            row_number() over (partition by employee order by opened) as cumopens,
            0 as cumcloses
     from eo
    ),
     cumcloses as
    (select employee, closed as thedate, 0 as cumopens,
            row_number() over (partition by employee order by closed ) as cumcloses
     from eo
    )
select employee, c.thedate, max(cumopens), max(cumcloses),
       max(cumopens) - max(cumcloses) as stillopened
from ((select *
       from cumopens
      ) union all
      (select *
       from cumcloses
      )
     ) c
group by employee, thedate
```

The only problem with this approach is that only dates where there is employee activity get reported.  This works in your case.

The more general solution requires a sequence numbers to generate dates.  For this, I often create one from some existing table with enough rows:

```
with nums as
    (select row_number() over (partition by null order by null) as seqnum
     from employees
    )
select employee, dateadd(day, opened, seqnum) as thedate, count(*)
from eo join
     nums
     on datediff(day, opened, closed) < seqnum
group by employee, dateadd(day, opened, seqnum)
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: Downvoted by accident, now I can't undo anymore. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT opened,employee,count(*)
FROM employee LEFT JOIN orders
WHERE opened < firstDate and opened > secondDate
GROUP BY opened,employee
```

or you can change the first condition in

```
WHERE opened BETWEEN firstDate and secondDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling the result column count was a bit odd because it seems to be in fact a row number. 
You can do that by using ROW_NUMBER.

The other interesting part is that you also want open date and close date as separate rows. Using a simple UNION will solve that.

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY employee  
                                    ORDER BY order_ref) count, 
                employee, 
                opened, 
                closed 
         FROM   orders) 
SELECT employee,  opened date,  count 
FROM   cte 
UNION ALL 
SELECT employee,  closed date,  count 
FROM   cte 
ORDER  BY Date, 
          employee
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6710f/8)