# SQL count open tasks each day

Tags: sql, date, between

I've tried to use the search function and found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209507/sql-count-of-open-orders-each-day-between-two-dates). However, I can't get it to work properly.

I have a simple table that shows incoming and ended e-mails (tasks). There's an ingoing and ended-date.

For analysis I want to show (historical) the number of open/unanswered e-mails for a given day back in time. The output should answer the question: "What was the number of open tasks yyyy-mm-dd?".

The number of open tasks a given day (yyyy-mm-dd) should be

```
Count WHERE Date_IN < yyyy-mm-dd 
AND Date_END >= yyyy-mm-dd 
OR Date_IN < yyyy-mm-dd AND Date_END Is Null
```

Hope this makes sense. It's a pretty simple "inventory report" where the inventory is tasks.

I've tried to [draw an output-example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvjRL.png) (When Date_END Is Null then task is still open).

Comment: Not sure which flavor of SQL you're using, but with Microsoft the `datetime` type has both a date and time component, so in order to include everything on a particular day you might need to strip the time off the datetime values. Otherwise it assumes that if your upper bound is say 10/15/2013, that boundary will be *midnight* of 10/15, so that values on that day with a time *after* midnight of that day won't get included.

Comment: You should give the queries you've tried that didn't work.

Comment: your pseudocode query seems correct to me, maybe you are feeding a wrong date. You have mixed up your date formats in your output example