# Oracle SQL Add up all open tasks for each day

Tags: oracle, aggregate

Vital Statistics:
    Oracle 11i
    I do not have the rights to create tables, or any kind of write access for that matter.

**Goal:**

I need to create a query that will look at the last 12 months of actions and count up (for each day) how many actions were open for each day. This must be a dynamic query without hard coded values.

The way I define an "Open" item is that it is approved on or before the day in question and released on or after the day in question.

**What I have tried:**

I found one similar question here that was not terribly well phrased and is unanswered. [SQL count open tasks each day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382314/sql-count-open-tasks-each-day)
Which leads to another question with some different ideas, but not the format I am looking for as I want to end up with a lot of rows.
[SQL Count Of Open Orders Each Day Between Two Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209507/sql-count-of-open-orders-each-day-between-two-dates)

Below is my code to date that is close, but excludes some results that I will describe after the code.

```
SELECT I.aggDate         ,
  eri.organization_id ORG,
  COUNT( (
  CASE
    WHEN OSD.date_approved < I.aggDate + interval '1' DAY
    AND osd.date_released  > I.aggDate - interval '1' DAY
    THEN 1
  END)) Items_in_DC
FROM mm_oracle_sig_dates osd ,
  ENG_REVISED_ITEMS ERI      ,
  (SELECT DISTINCT OSD.date_approved aggDate
  FROM mm_oracle_sig_dates osd
  WHERE OSD.date_approved >=TRUNC(sysdate) - interval '12' MONTH
  ) I
WHERE i.aggdate      = osd.date_approved
 and eri.change_notice    = osd.ecn_num
GROUP BY I.aggdate   ,
  eri.organization_id;
```

I am sure that the issue is the "i.aggdate      = osd.date_approved" because this causes the query to only add items approved on the day in question where I want to count all items approved on or before the day in question. I need to do some kind of explicit join to avoid an outside (I think) join that just creates chaos.

The purpose of the select in the FROM clause is to create a list of days on which at least one item was approved as I know that at least one item will be approved on each work day. 
My intent is to then populate that date list with the counts for each day.

**Final Sum-up  Question:**

How can I create an array of dates and then fill in a query by having the system count when that date is after or equal to date1 (approved date) **and** before or equal to date2 (release date).

I thank you in advance for reading through this long question. I give greater thanks to all constructive feedback and ideas.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Generate a list of all dates, with an indicator for whether the open count increases by 1 (approved) or decreases by one (released).  Then, a cumulative sum is your answer.  The following query does this, although you might want to tweak the results:

```
with dates as (
       (select greatest(osd.date_approved, trunc(sysdate) - interval '1 year' - interval '1 day') as dte,
               count(*) as inc
        from mm_oracle_sig_dates osd
        where osd.date_released >= trunc(sysdate) - interval '1 year' or 
              osd.date_released is null
        group by osd.date_approved
       ) union all
       (select osd.date_released + 1 as dte, -count(*) as inc
        from mm_oracle_sig_dates osd
        where osd.date_released >= trunc(sysdate) - interval '1 year' or
              osd.date_released is null
        group by osd.date_released
       )
      )
select dte,
       sum(sum(inc)) over (order by dte) as openitems
from dates
group by dte;
```

Notes:

- `dates` summarizes the data by approved and release date.  Note the release date is incremented by 1 to conform to your business rules.
- Only records that are not yet released or have been released in the past year are included in the population.  The same `where` clause is used for both subqueries.
- All approvals that are more than one year ago are aligned on the same date.
- The outer query then just does a cumulative sum by day.

If not all days are included in the result set, you can include them in `dates` with an `inc` value of `0`.

Comment: Gordon, Thank you for your help. This feels like the right direction to go, but I am getting results about two orders of magnitude larger than they should be. It feels like the missing piece is that the count bracketing is not right. It seems like this is including items that were both approved and released without requiring that the approval be before or on and the release be on or after.  Am I misreading this and the bracketing is implicit somehow?

Comment: @Corey . . . Are you sure you have the negative sign on `inc` in the second subquery?  Is it possible to show the problem in SQL Fiddle?

Comment: Gordon, sorry for the long delay I was off for the thanksgiving break. I started putting the thing in sql fiddle, but it gives me error messages about the number of columns in each row being wrong for straight CSV data. I'll keep working on it later today.