# SQL to find unique counts between two date fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, common-table-expression

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209507/sql-count-of-open-orders-each-day-between-two-dates) but can't manage to hack it to work on my own problem.

My data has the following fields, in a single table in Postgres:

- Seller_id (varchar) (contains_duplicates).
- SKU (varchar) (contains duplicates).
- selling_starts (datetime).
- selling_ends (datetime).

I want to query it so I get the count of *unique* SKUs on sale, per seller, per day. If there are any null days I don't need these.

I've tried before querying it by using another table to generate a list of unique "filler" dates and then joining it to where the date is more than the selling_starts and less than the selling_ends fields. However, this is so computationally expensive that I get timeout errors.

I'm vaguely aware there are probably more efficient ways of doing this via `with` statements to create CTEs or some sort of recursive function, but I don't have any experience of this.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Please also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
WITH list AS
( SELECT generate_series(date_trunc('day', min(selling_starts)), max(selling_ends), '1 day') AS ref_date
    FROM your_table
)
SELECT seller_id
     , l.ref_date
     , count(DISTINCT sku) AS sku_count
  FROM your_table AS t
 INNER JOIN list AS l
    ON t.selling_starts <= l.ref_date
   AND t.selling_ends > l.ref_date
 GROUP BY seller_id, l.ref_date
```

If your_table is large, you should create indexes to accelerate the query.